# Django | SuspiciousFileOperation error when creating a new profile object

Tags: django

I have an error when creating a new profile:

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /create_profil
The joined path C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\media\photo\2018\12\27\jhg.png) is 
located outside of the base path component 
(C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\media\)
```

UPDATE: This code worked correctly on Ubuntu OS on my colleague's machine. When I pulled the work from git repository it didn't work for me.
These are my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
print("---------------------------" + MEDIA_ROOT)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
```

This is my model:

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(default='defaut.png', upload_to='image/%Y/%m/%d', blank=False, null=True)
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Update: This is my `BASE_DIR`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: what is your `BASE_DIR`

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue for a couple of days. I found that changing the second argument in join from "media/" to "media" seemed to work, although I really couldn't tell you why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn/')`

Comment: can you chnage this just for test `upload_to='%Y%m%d'`

Comment: upload_to='media/'

Comment: if not then change the permission of the folder. The folder may not have write permissions

Comment: I changed it but I still have the same error. I'm working on windows. I tried this code on ubuntu and it worked. But when I changed to windows it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Add this to your urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    '''Here MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT is added to the urlpatterns.
       So that this will allow our media to work within the browser.
    '''
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```